# Is it possible to assign a value to a string array when using split?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have the below line of java script, which aims to split a string and replace the value at the splitted section with the new value. I appreciate this could be done with a 2-dimensional array, but I was wondering if there is a way of doing it this way.

```
measurementsArray[u].split(",")[3]="somenewstring";
```

Where `measurementsArray[u]` is `foo,bar,zee`, etc.

As I said, I am aware this can be done with a 2 dimensional array, but my code is existing and data is already formatted.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the original string, or the resulting array?  I imagine this would successfully modify the resulting array, but that array was never assigned to anything so this wouldn't really do much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `split`:

```
measurementsArray[u].split(",")
```

You actually return a **new** instance of  a `string[]` object. So, when you assign it with a new value, it will not be applied to the **original** array.

What you need to do is assign the value and return it back to the original array:

```
var newArray = measurementsArray[u].split(',');
newArray[3] = 'somenewstring';
measurementsArray[u] = newArray.join(',');
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much.

Comment: Well, it wasn't a correct answer until you corrected it by following Martin's comment. Now it is good, so +1 from me.

Comment: @RacilHilan Yeah I missed the `join`, I was too hastey. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the string is one good way among others. This is how you should do it:

```
var m = measurementsArray[u].split(",")
m[3] = "somenewstring";
measurementsArray[u] = m.join(",");
```